# Temperature prediction using artificial neural network

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I am using four parameters temperature, rainfall, humidity and date for the prediction. I am trying to predict a single parameter temperature. I am trying to use back propagation algorithm for training. What might be the best network structure for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You could start by setting up a Multilayer Perceptron with 4 input nodes, a single hidden layer(with multiple nodes) and one output node.

Train your network by feeding your testset (for example as .cvs) so that the first input node receives the temperature value, second the rainfall value and so on.

Note that can't use a date as input! Try to convert your date into a numeric value by for example just using the month of the year {1,..,12}, the week {1,..,52} or the day {1,..,365}.

I would also try to normalize my input value to the range of your activation function. So if you use the logistic function, normalize your data to the range [0,1] and for Tanh [-1,1] and so on. 
Your output value will be in the same range so you have to denormalize it afterwards. It's important that you choose a bijective function for the normalization process.